# sec:authorize and sec:authentication annotations don't work

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I have a Spring + Thymeleaf project with the following view code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-spring3-3.dtd">
<html
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
        xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">

<head>
    <title>Contacts</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <h1>Welcome to the site!</h1>
    <p th:if="${loginError}">Wrong user or password</p>
    <form th:action="@{/j_spring_security_check}" method="post">
        <label for="j_username">Email address</label>:
        <input type="text" id="j_username" name="j_username"/> <br/>
        <label for="j_password">Password</label>:
        <input type="password" id="j_password" name="j_password"/> <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Log in"/>
    </form>
</div>

<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
    User: <span sec:authentication="name">miquel</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The sec:authorize and sec:authentication attributes don't work as expected - the div is always shown, even if no user is logged in, and the span always reads "miquel".

Follows a relevant snippet from my controller class.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/welcome.html") 
public String wellcome() { 
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(); 
    System.out.println("username: " + auth.getName()); 

    return "home"; 
}
```

The println statement works as expected - if no user is logged in, it prints "anonymousUser", otherwise the username.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32904857/secauthorize-returning-true-for-both-isauthenticated-and-isanonymous-in-thy/40492335#40492335

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After comparing my application closely to the Thymeleaf & Spring Security demo applicaiton, I discovered the source of the error.

Apparently, in order for Thymeleaf to process the `sec:authorize` and `sec:authentication` attributes, you need to register `SpringSecurityDialect` as an additional dialect of the template engine bean.

```
<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
    <property name="additionalDialects">
        <set>
            <bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity3.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect" />
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This is surprising as there is no mention of that fact on [the related Thymeleaf documentation page](http://www.thymeleaf.org/springsecurity.html). I hope this helps others who will face the same issue in future.

Comment: Also don't forget to include the `thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3` maven dependency like I did

Answer (score 16):

In Spring Boot I just had to add the following dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This worked for me without configuring the SpringTemplateEngine bean. I am using Spring boot 1.4.1.RELEASE and Spring dependency management plugin 0.5.1.RELEASE

Answer (score 8):

For the java config version, it worked for me too by adding the spring security dialect:

```
 @Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    templateEngine.addDialect(new TilesDialect());
    templateEngine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
    return templateEngine;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you may wish to clear the template cache after an authentication event, so your template is re-processed with new authentication data. Or, set the templates which are sensitive to a login session to non-cached (this is what I did), using `ServletContextTemplateResolver.setNonCacheablePatterns()`.