# Thymeleaf is not parsing "sec:authorize" attribute

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm using **thymeleaf-spring3 2.0.18** and **Spring 3.1.1**. I've done a Login page that works ok but, while other Thymeleaf attributes are parsed, "sec:authorize" aren't, since I can see them if I review source code of generated view.

Is there something I'm missing, like a dependecy or specific configuration?

This is my login.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
...
</head> 

<body>
<div class="top">
    <div class="container">         
        <ul class="loginbar pull-right">
            <li sec:authorize="isAnonymous()"><a href="/login" class="login-btn">Login</a></li>   
            <li sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" class="login-btn">Welcome <span sec:authentication="name">Bob</span></li>   
        </ul>
    </div>      
</div><!--/top-->

<!--=== Content Part ===-->
<div class="container">     
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <form name="f" th:action="@{/j_spring_security_check}" method="post" class="log-page">
            <h3>Login</h3>
            <div th:if="${loginError}" th:with="errorMsg=${session['SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION'].message}" class="alert alert-error">
                Bad user or password.<br/>
                Cause: <span th:text="${errorMsg}">Wrong input!</span>
            </div>    
            <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                <input name="j_username" class="input-xlarge" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
                <input name="j_password" class="input-xlarge" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
            </div>
            <div class="controls form-inline">
                <button class="btn-u pull-right" type="submit">Login</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div><!--/row-fluid-->
</div><!--/container-->     
<!--=== End Content Part ===-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [sec:authorize and sec:authentication annotations don't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309864/secauthorize-and-secauthentication-annotations-dont-work)

Comment: Note: If you are using Spring boot, only adding the dependency should be enough. This worked for me without configuring the SpringTemplateEngine bean. I am using Spring boot 1.4.1.RELEASE and Spring dependency management plugin 0.5.1.RELEASE

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By looking to [this example](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleafexamples-springsecurity) I realized that I need to add a dependency to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

And also need to add additional dialect to the `templateEngine` bean:

```
<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver"/>
    <property name="additionalDialects">
        <set>
            <bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity3.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Using Spring Boot 1.3.3 - project init using start.spring.io - sec:authorize also did not work before manually adding dep to project pom.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue and we resolved it by adding a package scan in the main controller context configuration:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity3" />
```