# Undefined attribute name (sec:authentication)

Tags: spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm using Thymleaf in my spring security simple POC. Below is my sample code in home.html file.

```
Hello <span sec:authentication="name">User</span>!i
```

How to get rid of the html warning

```
Undefined attribute name (sec:authentication).
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I Just duplicate the namespace for sec tag and html warning disappear

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

Answer (score 4):

Joel's answer works well But this is the Proper Name Space Suggested in the [Official Guidelines](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity)

> xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security"

Answer (score 0):

1) Add this dependency to `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0.BETA01</version>
</dependency>
```

2) Add additional dialect to `templateEngine` bean:

```xml
<!-- Thymeleaf Template Engine (Spring4-specific version) -->
<bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolvers">
        <set>
            <ref bean="templateResolver" />
        </set>
    </property>
    <property name="additionalDialects">
        <set>
             <bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity3.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect" />
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I've added these libraries and configuration. I think this is not the solution for the issue.

Comment: @fuzzy28 did you look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309864/secauthorize-and-secauthentication-annotations-dont-work ?