# Thymeleaf template not showing username

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

My home page is not showing the username, I am using sec:authentication tag

```html
<li sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"><a th:href="@{/logout}">Logout</a></li>
   </ul>
   </div>
   </nav>
   <br><br>
   <p>
   Welcome <span sec:authentication="principal.username">User</span>
   </p>
```

Comment: Do any of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309864/secauthorize-and-secauthentication-annotations-dont-work) help?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```xml
<p>
  Welcome <span th:text="${#request.userPrincipal.name}">User</span>
</p>
```

Comment: can you suggest how to fetch other details of user